# Compile Boost Spirit Keyword Parser Example

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am having some trouble compiling the example code for boost keyword parser. I am using `boost 1.63.0` and `gcc 6.3.0` and specifying c++ 11. I ran:

`g++ -std=c++11 -I boost-1.63-0/include keywords-1.cpp`

and was hit by a massive wall of compiler errors. 
The first error was:

`no type named 'type' in struct boost::mpl::apply...`

I also tried compiling the example using `gcc 4.8.2` with the c++ 11 flag turned on with boost 1.55.0 and also received a similarly large wall of errors. However, trying to compile the example with c++ 03, both compilers and boost versions worked.

I have tried compiling on Centos 5 and Ubuntu 14.04. The specific example I am referencing can be found under `spirit/repository/example/qi/keywords.cpp`

Does anyone know if the keyword parser is will compile in c++11, or should I go back to using the Nabialek trick for these purposes? Or does anyone have any points in the correct direction or hints as to what I am doing incorrect?

Comment: Can you format the question to be readable? Will be back later tonight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have the answer I tried compiling with `g++ -I boost-1.63.0/include -DBOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1 ~/keywords.cpp` and it compiles. This solution was found in a bug report here: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11493

Comment: Correct, fixed.